# Inject a bean which is filled in a different class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

Suppose i have 2 files

```
A.java

@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor =  @__(@Autowired))
@Component
public class A {
    private bean1 bean1_name1;
    bean1_name.property1 = "Value1"
}


B.java

public class B {
    private bean1 bean1_name2;

}
```

I want to autoinject the bean1 object which was modified in A.java to be injected in class B.
So basically when i call bean1_name2 it should already have the bean1_name.property1 = "Value1" in it.
Obviously this assumes that class A runs before class B.

Please do let me know if you need more context.

Thank You.

Comment: Would it be an option to make bean1_name.property1 static?

Comment: Yeah i think, that is something that we can do

Comment: Basically i can always pass the bean1 object to class B, but the goal here is to use spring in order to inject it without using extra memory.

Comment: Why is the bean modified in another component? If you want the bean to have properties initialized, do it when you initialize the bean before it's injected anywhere, not trying to "intercept" it in a component.

Comment: the bean is modified in another component because its jsut the way the code present is. I dont want to initialize anything in the bean because the value would be changing in class A when the code would be executing for real. So i need a way to keep that changing value the same in both A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking property1 of bean1 as `static` solves the problem. The static keyword indicates that the particular member belongs to a type itself, rather than to an instance of that type. This means that only one instance of that static member is created which is shared across all instances of the class.